# In Bootsrap 4 how to set dropdown menu to open in position on botom of navabr height

Tags: dropdown

In Bootsrap 4 how to set dropdown menu to open in position on botom of navabr height

[click to show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sWD8.jpg)

default dropdown is always below .nav-link
i want to be below navbar

Answer (score 0):

there will be a .dropdown-menu class which contains margins associated with the drop down change the margins to adjust the drop according to your need

Comment: i change dropdown. is open when i hover not click, when i add margin if i set cursor above button then menu close